# execute javascript every time I call its twig template

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I have a php script that calls another script through a for loop. The script that is called then echos a twig template that has a javascript attached to it which exports a pdf. The issue is that the javascript only executes once. Here's the flow:

generate-invoice.php -> invoice.php -> twig template that has a script tag ->
the code of that javascript is:

```
window.onload = function() {
  kendo.pdf.defineFont({
      "Comfortaa": "/doc/fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf",
      "Comfortaa|Bold": "/doc/fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf",
  });

  var inv_num = document.querySelector('#inv_num').dataset.id;
  var company = document.querySelector('#company').dataset.id;

  function ExportPdf(){ 
      kendo.drawing
      .drawDOM("#myCanvas", 
      {
      paperSize: "A4",
      margin: { top: "0.5cm", bottom: "0.5cm", left: "0.5cm", right: "0.5cm" 
},
      scale: 0.8,
      height: 500
      })
      .then(function(group){
      kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group,company + " | Invoice #" + inv_num + 
".pdf")
      });
  }

  ExportPdf();
  console.log('It ran');
}
```

And when I look in the console, 'it ran' is only posted once where as it should be posted twice because the twig template was called 2 times.

EDIT: Just wanted to let you know that I'm calling the invoice.php script by `include`ing it in a for loop.. maybe that's what's causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have your string logged twice or as many times as the script was called, move the statement into the `ExportPdf() function`

calling it from `window.inload` will only run once, and that's the first time window was loaded.

```
window.onload = function() {
  kendo.pdf.defineFont({
      "Comfortaa": "/doc/fonts/Comfortaa-Regular.ttf",
      "Comfortaa|Bold": "/doc/fonts/Comfortaa-Bold.ttf",
  });

  var inv_num = document.querySelector('#inv_num').dataset.id;
  var company = document.querySelector('#company').dataset.id;

  function ExportPdf(){ 
      kendo.drawing
      .drawDOM("#myCanvas", 
      {
      paperSize: "A4",
      margin: { top: "0.5cm", bottom: "0.5cm", left: "0.5cm", right: "0.5cm" 
      },
      scale: 0.8,
      height: 500
      })
      .then(function(group){
      kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(group,company + " | Invoice #" + inv_num + ".pdf")
      });
      //Moved here
      console.log('It ran');
  }

  ExportPdf();
}
```

EDITED:
window.onload will only fire once and never except there was a browser refresh. The get the desired result, I'll suggest you place the function outside of `window.onload`. In that case, in your HTML/JavaScript code, you'll need to wrap the main function that calls the template in your `.onload`.